# Spring Controller - Map JSON Attribute to foreign key Entity

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

### `UserController.java`

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    // code
    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        //code
    }
}
```

### `User`

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id")
    private Language language;

    // others
    public User() {
    }
}
```

So, as you see, `Language` is an independent entity. But I want to be able to send the following `JSON` structure

```
{
    "foreName" : "bla",
    "sureName" : "blo",
    "language" : "1"
}
```

But I receive the following error

> Cannot construct instance of `entity.db.user.Language` (although at
>   least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory
>   method to deserialize from String value ('1');

Do I need to go through a filter to fetch the `Language` entity beforehand? Is there a form to force a parsing method? What is the way to do it properly here?

Comment: Create a new DTO Object as Request body. Process the DTO to form the User entity, to proceed further.

Comment: @PrakashAyappan Gosh why didn't I think of that :) Add an answer that I'll accept

Comment: It happens in Developers life!

Comment: Same issue im stuck with, can you please help me elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new DTO Object, Say UserDTO, as Request Body in your API Method. Process the DTO to form the User entity, to proceed further.